# Horizontal list with Webix - is it possible?

Tags: user-interface, listview, webix

Is it possible to arrange `list` items horizontally with Webix and preserve all customization and functionality?

I need to create something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YbrX3/1296/ - this is not my own snippet, just for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the layout arrangement with the `layout:"x"` parameter

```
webix.ui({
    view:"list",
    scroll:"x",
    layout:"x",
    select:true,
    data: ...
});
```

Here's the explanation:
http://docs.webix.com/desktop__xlist.html